# Render HTML in $uibModal body

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I have the following Angular UI Modal:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="dialogBox">
        <div class="modal-header">
             <p class="modal-title"><b>{{title}}</b></p>
        </div>

            {{msg}}

        <div class="modal-footer">
               <button class="btn btn-primary b1" type="submit">OK</button>
        </div>
</script>
```

What I want is to set `msg` with HTML markup, such as `"This is a <b>text</b>"`. I tried, however the HTML is not rendered (the modal shows the markup). Is this achievable?

Comment: have you tried ngBindHtml? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use ngHtmlbind. It requires angular-sanitize.js (you have to add ngSanitize to your module dependencies). You also have to declare the html you want to render is safe using $sce.trustAsHtml. For example:

The javascript:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myModule', ['ngSanitize']);

  angular
    .module('myModule')
    .controller('showHtmlCtrl', showHtmlCtrl);

  showHtmlCtrl.$inject = ['$sce'];
  function showHtmlCtrl($sce){
    var vm = this;
    var html = "<p> Hello world! </p>";
    vm.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
  }

})();
```

The view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@~1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-sanitize@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="showHtmlCtrl as shc">
    <div ng-bind-html="shc.html"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can see it working this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZCwLnmC1AQSzTiJtNS0y?p=preview)